# How Do I Display a TextBlock In Front of a MediaElement In Fullscreen?

Tags: vb.net, xaml, textblock, mediaelement

I'm creating a simple movie/music player Windows Store app in Visual Studio 2013 using VB.net and XAML.

I am using a MediaElement and when it is set as IsFullWindow = True, all my controls are hidden behind it.

Is there a way that I can show a TextBlock in front of the MediaElement so that I can add in subtitles?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Microsoft Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/) in order to display subtitles instead of trying to display the subtitles yourself.

If for some reason you *have* to do it yourself, then you won't be able to use the IsFullWindow property, you will have to [create a custom full-screen player as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx).